# How to play midi files?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server

In my SharePoint portal I have a document library that contains some midi files.  I want to also create a regular page with a method of playing those files so the user can listen to them.

How can I play a midi file in Sharepoint 2010?
Is there something built-in or do I have to use an external solution?

I know about the [Media Player webpart](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sanjaynarang/archive/2010/05/26/media-web-part-in-sharepoint-2010-faq.aspx), but it doesn't seem to play midi files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a Google search for "embed MIDI player", [one of the top hits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677366/about-embed-midi-files-on-a-webpage) recommends using the [HTML5 "audio" tag](http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/).

You could build a page, and either manipulate the source for the audio tag in code-behind or through Javascript.

But there is no built in solution, you would have to find some way to do it yourself.

---

While BGM is correct in saying that MIDI files are not audio files themselves, but sets of instructions that tell a MIDI interpreter (a.k.a. synthesizer) what notes to play, that doesn't necessarily mean you can't get them to play.

You just can't play them with the Media Player web part.

But with a little hunting around, you can find things like [MIDI.js](http://www.midijs.net/), a JavaScript MIDI player.

I've never used it, so I can't vouch for it's functionality (or lack thereof), but using something like that (or some other web-hosted MIDI player), you could theoretically create a page in SharePoint that will be able to play your MIDI files.

Comment: You are right.  It isn't possible.  I posted a solution as well with the reason why.

Comment: @BGM actually I was trying to say it *is* possible, just not through SP web parts.  You'd need a custom solution.  I've updated my answer with a link to a JavaScript MIDI player.  :)

Comment: Thanks for the link - I'll look at that.  However, I'm also going to try converting midi files to mp3s with audacity.  I'll try both, in fact.  Let me think about this for a little while and then I'll probably accept your answer (mostly because I don't like accepting my own...).

Comment: I just used Audacity to do this and it was soooo easy.  I'll update my answer with that but I'm going to accept yours.

Comment: Yep, Audacity is super easy to work with.  Glad you found a solution.  Just want to also point out (for future readers) that there may very well be a use case where you want the MIDI files to remain MIDI files (collaboration site for composers?), but still be able to have some sort of audio preview, in which case you would want to use a MIDI player to directly play the files, and not convert them to some other audio format.  But, if there is no risk of the files needing to change, converting them will definitely get them in a format that SP can play natively in the Media Player web part.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the Midi files, but you can try:

- You can configure dynamic displays of video or audio by configuring
  the Content Editor Web Part to display audio or video files.
- Or you can embed a video from a third-party video sharing site by
  using embed code.

Read more here [Play video and media files in SharePoint 2010 sites](http://sharepointconnoisseur.blogspot.com/2011/05/play-video-and-media-files-in.html)

- Another approach is to use SharePoint 2010 to play audio or video
  media files on Media server
- Use third-party media player to play audio or video media file
- or you can think about to convert MIDI files into the supported format.[Supported Media Formats, Protocols, and Log Fields](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189080(VS.95).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Well!  The answer is this:

**NO**.

**And here is why:**

You see, midi (`.mid`) files are not sound files at all! They are sets of ***directions*** that describe to a midi-interpreter what tones to play and how long to play them.

And you can't really convert them to another format, per se, for the same reason that you can't convert apples to hot dogs - they are not of a like nature.  But what does happen when you "convert" a midi file to wav or mp3 is you play the midi file using a midi player and then record the outputted sound using a regular audio sound recorder.  [Here's some wiki-how directions of how to do this using Audacity](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-an-MP3-or-WAV-out-of-a-MIDI-Using-Audacity).  There are some applications that will do for you exactly this - [this is an example](http://www.downloadatoz.com/midi2wav-recorder/midi-to-wav.html), and it works (I tried it), but you have to play with the settings.

Now, back to getting these files to play in Sharepoint - no, you can't play midi files at all.  But you can create an audio file from them (see last paragraph) and then [use sharepoint's built-in media player](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sanjaynarang/archive/2010/05/26/media-web-part-in-sharepoint-2010-faq.aspx).

---

**How to Make an mp3 from a midi using Audacity**

You can very easily make an audio file from a midi file using Audacity.  There is a [page here about how to record sound played by your computer](http://manual.audacityteam.org/o/man/tutorial_recording_computer_playback_on_windows.html) [and here, too](http://manual.audacityteam.org/o/man/tutorial_recording_audio_playing_on_the_computer.html). But I'm providing a screenshot.

[image]

What is important here is that you set the appropriate devices:

- Audio Host = WASAPI
- Speakers = your regular computer speakers
- Input device = your regular computer speakers

This works *very* well. I was surprised how easy.  When I was finished I used `File > Export` and chose .mp3 for lossless sound and I had perfect-sounding 455kb mp3 file that my Sharepoint Media player will play.

**Final Tip:**

When you configure the Sharepoint Media Player Webpart, know that it is kind of unsuited to playback for an audio file, but to make it more obviously an audio player and not a video player you can set the height to `90px` - if you make it any smaller the lines around the play button will get cut off (at least when you hover over the play button) and it will be ugly (but you can reduce it to `50px` if you don't mind that).  I placed a link to a pdf in a document library below mine.

[image]